# Iterative column fill for pandas dataframe if value has new data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on pandas data frame. Go stuck at some logic .Can any one help:

Here is my input data frame :

```
**df4**

Data1   Description Associated Data
F104    TO  F5334
F104    TO  F105
F105    TO  F1212
F105    TO  F5332
F105    IS  F104
F5332   IS  F105
F5334   IS  F104
F1000   IS  F1212
F1015   IS  F1242
F1015B  IS  F1242B
F1015B  IS  F1242
F1212   TO  F1000
F1212   TO  F1242B
F1212   IS  F105
F1242   TO  F1015
F1242   TO  F1015B
F1242B  TO  F1015B
F1242B  IS  F1212
```

Here there are 3 columns:
Data1(Key) , Description (which is used as condition) , Associated Data (Value)

Expected Output :

```
F104    F5334       
F104    F105    F1212 
F104    F105    F5332   
F104    F105    F1212 F1000 
F104    F105    F1212 F1242B
...............
```

My code :

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Is_Upgrade"])
df4 = df.copy()
for i in range(len(df4)):
    print(i)
    bas_part = df4.loc[i]["Data1"]
    type_part = df4.loc[i]["Description"]
    #associate = df4.loc[i]["Associated Data"]
    if((str(type_part) == "TO") == True):
        df6.loc[i,"Data1"]= str(bas_part)
        df6.loc[i,"Upgrade_use"] = df4.loc[i]["Associated Data"]
    elif((str(type_part) == "IS") == True):
        #if(df6.loc[i]["Upgrade"] == ""):
            df6.loc[df6["Data1"]== str(bas_part),"Is_Upgrade"] = df4.loc[i]["Associated Data"]
```

Results obtained :

```
F104    F105    F1212
F104    F105    F5332
F105    F1212   F1000
F105    F1212   F1242B
nan     F104    F5334
nan     F104    F105
F1212   F1242B  F1015B
nan     F1242   F1015
nan     F1242   F1015B
```

Detailed Description:

If the Description column value is "TO" Then add the associate data to the right of actual data.

Iteration 1:

```
F104, F5334
```

Iteration 2: as we have condition To again create new row with same value

```
F104 F5334
F104 F105
```

Iteration 3: as we have condition To again create new row with same value

```
F104 F5334
F104 F105 F1212
```

Iteration 4: as we have condition To again create new row with same value

```
F104 F5334
F104 F105 F1212
F104 F105 F5332
```

Iteration 5: as we have condition "IS" now check does the value left of data1 is same as associate if "yes" Pass else Add the new value shift it existing data to new column

```
F104 F5334
F104 F105 F1212
F104 F105 F5332
```

Iteration 7: as we have condition "IS" now check does the value left of data1 is same as associate if "yes" Pass else Add the new value shift it existing data to new column

```
F104 F5334
F104 F105 F1212
F104 F105 F5332
```

So on.....

Can someone help?

Comment: it is somewhat unclear, what the structure of the expected output shall be. A df with 2 columns, the first with an index and the second a list with all the added values OR a df that grows in columns with every addition?

Comment: Yes @Racooneer, It grows with every addition. if we find out condition "TO" is correct as explained in iteration 3 and 8 .

Comment: What happened to iteration 6 ??

Comment: well, it seems like your code doesn't follow that idea: you define 3 columns for df6 `Is_Upgrade`, `Data1` and `Upgrade_use`. Where do you think the new columns, that grows dynamically, should come from? ...and by the way, what is df5 doing in all this?

Comment: @Racooneer, Df5 was typo here . Had stored DF4 values as copy for testing purpose.

Comment: Yes @Racooneer, The logic created by me is static columns that is why i got the results as displayed above. How can i do it dynamically as expected output ?? Can you please help

Comment: @marc_s, Iteration 6 already has value . "IS" condition so we need to check . If exist do nothing else shift the value add the new value on your left side or before the existing data as show in Iteration 8.

Comment: tbh, after reading this twice, I'm still not completely sure I understand the alogrithm you would need. However,  you would try to use `iloc` instead of `loc` to let t grow dynamically, somthing like `df6.iloc[i,1:]`. However, from what I get of your intent, I'd recommend to split this in two parts. First identify the steps that lead to copies (iteration 4), and merge in the second step. And I don't think a pandas DF is the right structure for you, maybe if you consider having a list in the column that grows instead of growing the columns.

Comment: @Racooneer, To further simply my problem. Let us consider 1 value i.e F104 . Check for description(i.e condition) . It is "TO" So we should create 2 columns, 1 Data1 and another dynamic column C1 as associate value . later value changes F105 add another column dynamically as show in iteration 3 and so on

Comment: @Racooneer, it is like checking values lest and right data for each base data.i.e 
F104 has only right value , But F105 has both right and left values as per condition

Comment: no5 and no8 contradict... in no5 you check whether F105 (Data1) is in the chain and F104 (associate) left from it if (Yes --> pass), in no8 you check whether F1212 (associate) is in the chain and F1000 (data1) left from it (No, add left)! Please check your example!!!

Comment: @Racooneer,Is it possible to use lists and add new list as new row if the value already exists??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods to do this is create a function for checking the index value in a dataframe :

```
def right_tree_pn(df5,base_partnum):
 if(len(df5) == 0):
            parts_list = []
 else:
            new_pn_list = df5
            parts_list = new_pn_list.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").split(", ")
 if(base_partnum in parts_list):
     base_index = "Yes"
 else :
     base_index = "No"
 
 return base_index
```

Now create a for loop :

```
for i in range(len(df4)):
    print(i)
    base = df4.loc[i]["Data1"]
    type_part = df4.loc[i]["Description"]
    associate_data = df4.loc[i]["Associated Data"]
    test_parts2 = base + "," + associate_data
    test_parts =test_parts2.split(",")
    #check for condition
    if((str(type_part) == "TO") == True):
    #initially the data frame is empty
        if(len(df5) == 0):
           parts_list = []
     ## Check for value . it is 0 for first step
           if(len(parts_list) > 0):
                index = parts_list.index(base)
                #index_val = len(df5)
           else:
                index = 0
                index_val = len(df5)
               # Insert to first Position as index i.e base value
                parts_list.insert(index, base)
           if(associate_data in parts_list):
                associate_index = parts_list.index(associate_data)
           else:
                associate_index = index
        #########################################
           if((associate_index < index) or (associate_index > index) == True):
            #df5.loc[new_index,"Data"] =  str(parts_list)
                pass
           else:
                #add Associate data to next index value i.1 1 for first step
                 parts_list.insert(index + 1,associate_data)
           df5.loc[index_val ,"Data"] = str(parts_list)
           df5.loc[index_val ,"Base_PN"] = str(parts_list[0])
   ######### Add to new line if dataframe is not empty 
        else:
            df_index = []
    ###############Get the index values from the dataframe if the base data exists
            for x in range(len(df5)):
                df6 = right_tree_pn(df5.loc[x]["Data"],base)
                if(str(df6) == "Yes"):
                    df_index1 = x
                    df_index.append(df_index1)
#Check length of the index if it is 1 perform following operations
            if(len(df_index) == 1):
                df_index = df_index[0]
                new_pn_list = df5.loc[df_index]["Data"]
                parts_list1 = new_pn_list.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").replace(" ","").split(",")
                ######List compare
                if(all(w in parts_list1 for w in test_parts) == True):
                    pass
                else:
                    index = parts_list1.index(base)
                    if((index == 0 and len(parts_list1) != 0)) == True:
                        ass_pasrt2 = parts_list1[index + 1]
                        if(index == 0 and associate_data != ass_pasrt2) == True:
                            parts_list = []
                            index_val = len(df5)
                        else:
                             parts_list = parts_list1
                             index_val = df_index
                    elif(((index == 0 and len(parts_list1) == 0)) ==True):
                            parts_list = []
                            index_val = len(df5)
                    else:
                        index2 = len(parts_list1) - 1
                        if(index2 != index):
                            ass_pasrt2 = parts_list1[index + 1]
                        else:
                            ass_pasrt2 = ""
                        if((associate_data == ass_pasrt2)== True):
                            parts_list = parts_list1
                            index_val = df_index
                        elif((ass_pasrt2 == "") == True):
                            parts_list = parts_list1
                            index_val = df_index
                        else:
                            parts_list = parts_list1
                            if(ass_pasrt2 in parts_list):
                                parts_list.remove(ass_pasrt2)
                            index_val = len(df5)
                    if(len(parts_list) > 0):
                        index = parts_list.index(base)
                    else:
                            index = 0
                            parts_list.insert(index, base)
                    if(associate_data in parts_list):
                        associate_index = parts_list.index(associate_data)
                    else:
                        associate_index = index
        #########################################
                    if((associate_index < index) or (associate_index > index) == True):
            #df5.loc[new_index,"Data"] =  str(parts_list)
                        pass
                    else:
                        parts_list.insert(index + 1,associate_data) 
                        parts_list2 = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(parts_list))
                    df5.loc[index_val,"Data"] = str(parts_list2)
                    df5.loc[index_val ,"Base_PN"] = str(parts_list2[0])
  #### If the base is not present in the data frame create new row similar to first iteration
            elif(len(df_index) == 0):
                parts_list = []
                if(len(parts_list) > 0):
                    index = parts_list.index(base)
                    #index_val = len(df5)
                else:
                    index = 0
                    parts_list.insert(index, base)
                    index_val = len(df5)
                if(associate_data in parts_list):
                    associate_index = parts_list.index(associate_data)
                else:
                    associate_index = index
        #########################################
                if((associate_index < index) or (associate_index > index) == True):
            #df5.loc[new_index,"Data"] =  str(parts_list)
                    pass
                else:
                    parts_list.insert(index + 1,associate_data)
                df5.loc[index_val ,"Data"] = str(parts_list)
                df5.loc[index_val ,"Base_PN"] = str(base)
            else:
#Code for multiple index data 
                for z in range(len(df_index)):
                    index_value = df_index[z]
                    new_pn_list = df5.loc[index_value]["Data"]
                    parts_list1 = new_pn_list.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").split(", ")
                    if(all(w in parts_list1 for w in test_parts) == True):
                        pass
                    else:
                        index = parts_list1.index(base)
                        if((index == 0 and len(parts_list1) != 0)) ==True:
                            parts_list = parts_list1
                        elif(((index == 0 and len(parts_list1) == 0)) ==True):
                            parts_list = []
                        else:
                            parts_list = parts_list1
                    #    parts_list = parts_list1
                    if(len(parts_list) > 0):
                        index = parts_list.index(base)
                    else:
                            index = 0
                            parts_list.insert(index, base)
                    if(associate_data in parts_list):
                        associate_index = parts_list.index(associate_data)
                    else:
                        associate_index = index
        #########################################
                    if((associate_index < index) or (associate_index > index) == True):
            #df5.loc[new_index,"Data"] =  str(parts_list)
                        pass
                    else:
                        parts_list.insert(index + 1,associate_data)
                        parts_list2 = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(parts_list))
                    df5.loc[index_value ,"Data"] = str(parts_list2)
                    df5.loc[index_value ,"Base_PN"] = str(parts_list2[0])
```

Once the Data frame is create now we will have to split the data into multiple columns:

```
df5 = df5[["Base_PN","Data"]]                   
df5["Data2"] = df5["Data"].str.replace("[","").str.replace("]","").str.replace("'","").str.replace(" ","")
df6 = df5.Data2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(","))).add_prefix('Level_')
```

Output :

```
Level_0 Level_1 Level_2 Level_3 Level_4 
----------------------------------------
F104    F5334       
F104    F105    F1212 
F104    F105    F5332   
F104    F105    F1212 F1000 
F104    F105    F1212 F1242B    F1015B
```